# Code Summarizer, inline comments generator for already written c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am reviewing a huge code base written in C# and aspx(*.aspx and .aspx.cs) and realize that I may end up using tools like CodeMap, Dependency diagrams, etc. to understand the flow. I was wondering if there is a plugin or something which can generate a summary for already written code. Something like GhostDoc I guess, but GhostDoc summarizes what it sees in the name of the function and not what and all is going on inside a function. Maybe I will end up writing notes from the code to better understand some major business logic, but I was wondering if you(SO community) have used some sort of intelligent tool, which can spit out in plain English as to what the code is trying to do and maybe capable of adding inline comments to few(if not all) lines of code within the function.

Pardon me if this seems ambitious or lazy of me, I plan to eventually get down to writing my understanding of the code if I do not find any tool to help save the day.

Comment: I very doubt a tool can generate *meaningful* comments of the real purpose of the code being analyzed. Not only spaghetti code gets in the wayt, programs are utterly lost at the underling business logic that code is trying to implement. Not to mention if it contains bugs.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of felt the same but was hoping if there is an artificially intelligent tool, which can predict as what the code is trying to do, and spit it out in plain english.